# OrderBy, GetNewBindingList and Linq to SQL

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I have a background worker that performs loading of data from the database into a temporary structure.

```
Data d = new Data();
d.listGroup = context.Groups.GetNewBindingList();
d.tbUser = context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Name);        
d.listPriceLevel = context.PriceLevels.GetNewBindingList();
e.Result = d;
```

The problem is that the 3rd line (d.tbUser = ... ) is being lazy-loaded.
Sure, I can do:

```
context.Users.OrderBy( x => x.Name ).ToList();
```

But then again, this is not a Bindable List, any changes made to it won't propagate back to the DB.

So I think I need something like:

```
d.tbUser = context.Users.OrderBy( x => x.Name ).GetNewBindingList();
```

But that doesn't work.
The goal is: retrieve a list of users, ordered by their name as a bind-able list.
Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `OrderBy` (like any of the other query functions) turns your query into an `IQueryable<TEntity>`. Fortunately, LINQ-to-SQL's internal query type (`DataQuery<TEntity>`) provides a `BindingList<TEntity>` via its implementation of `IListSource`.

To get a `BindingList` for a given query, you can do this:

```
var bindingList = ((IListSource)query).GetList();
```

In your case:

```
d.tbUser = ((IListSource)context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Name)).GetList();
```

While the return type of `GetList` is `IList`, it is, in fact, an actual `BindingList<User>`.